# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.commands.__init__.context'

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, pycord

I'm currently working on a program that controls my PC with discord commands. For discord library, I use Pycord. After converting the file into an Executable file, it shows the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "discord\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495 in exec_module
  File "discord\commands\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord.commands.__init__.context'
[16680] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

```
pip uninstall discord
pip uninstall discord.py
pip uninstall py-cord
```

Then:

```
pip install discord
```

I had installed a different library related to Discord, so I think that was the issue <3